# Autodesk Forge viewer cannot load my model (error code 7)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed the forge tutorial and upload a model, translated to SVF, then try to load it in a simple HTML page(Basic Viewer) and got this error. Can you give me some hint of the root cause? I double checked the URN and token many times and didn't have a clue.

error message in brief:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

[Error message in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Hl8.png)
Can anyone help out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the query string of the request URL you provided, it seems that your Forge app didn't be hosted on a web server. In other hands, your HTML file is opened by the web browser from your OS's file system directly.

```
domain=file%3A%2F%2F can be decoded to domain=file://
```

Forge Viewer is based on the Web technology, it uses XMLHttpRequest to fetch viewables from our Forge MD service.

Due to the browser implementation and security policies, XMLHttpRequest cannot be used while your HTML file is opened from the file system (file://) directly. So, please make sure your Forge app is hosted on a web server and you access it from valid url from your web server.

Here is a discussion I found on the Google Chrome Forum:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/v177zA6LCKU